# How to used ui-view nested inside another ui-view with a single state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview

I am working on a personal project, and I am trying to nest a ui-view inside another while working with a single state.

So this is the thing, the url has 2 params, the second param is optional, so if the user adds the second param I'll show additional information inside the page I'm loading.

Here is part of the code:

app.js

```
.state('students', {
        url: '/students/:id/grade/:num',
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            return $stateParams.students + '.html';
        },
        controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
            var Ctrlname = $stateParams.students + 'Ctrl';
            return Ctrlname;
        }
```

index.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="students({id: '1', grade: ''})">Student 1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="students({id: '2', grade: ''})">Student 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view></div>
```

1.html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="">Math</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="">English</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="">History</a></li>
   </ul>
```

So my doubt in here is, how would I achieve this, using a single state. Do I have to add additional information on the app.js and what do I put in the ui-sref of the 1.html file ?

Answer (score 0):

This block:

```
 templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
        return $stateParams.students + '.html';
    },
```

suggests you have several templates per student. Ideally you should have one template with dynamic contents.

What you require can be achieved with a simple `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

So your controller might have something like:

`if ($stateParams.num) {
  $scope.gradeNum = $stateParams.num
  ...
}`

And in the template:

`<div ng-show="">.....Grade Additional Info</div>`

Comment: yes I know this would be the best way put I need to do it with another ui-view.